# Upgradewindows phone 8 project

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to upgrade a recent project that I started developping with windows phone 8 sdk and continue it with windows phone 8.1 or do I have to restart from scratch

Comment: Yes it is possible - to WP8.1 Silverlight. Have you tired?

Comment: Yeah I tried but i am stack with Dispatcher class of the namespace System.Windows.Threading. I could not find this namespace in windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight Application) then you don't need to start from scratch, you will be able to upgrade from your Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight Project) but if you want to target Windows Phone 8.1 (New Universal App API's) then you will have to develop your application from scratch.

Here this will help you understand better [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642081%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)